# Loop to make circle grow

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, processing

Could anyone help me out with a loop that will make the ellipses forming the flower grow. 
there are 5 ellipses acting as petals and the one center flower ellipse.

```
Stem myStem;
Circle circles[];

float scaleFactor=0.5;

void setup() {


size(floor(400*scaleFactor), floor(800*scaleFactor));
myStem = new Stem(200,800);
//mpoved this to setup, no need to recreate each frame
circles = new Circle[6];
circles[0]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
circles[1]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
circles[2]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
circles[3]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
circles[4]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
circles[5]  = new Circle(0, 0, 50, 50);
// also smooth only needs to be called once
// unless ther is a noSmooth() somewhere
// smooth();
}

void draw() {

  float grow = 0;
  //translate(myStem.initalloX, myStem.initalloY);  
  myStem.drawStem();
  //set centre point
  if (frameCount>grow) {
    translate(myStem.initalloX, ((frameCount>250)?myStem.initalloY-      500:myStem.initalloY-(2*frameCount)));
    fill(170, 14, 24); // red
    for (int i = 0; i < circles.length-1; i++) {
      ellipse(circles[i].c1+grow, circles[i].c2+grow, circles[i].c3+grow, circles[i].c4+grow);
      rotate(radians(72));
    }
    fill(14, 17, 170); // blue
    ellipse(circles[5].c1, circles[5].c2, circles[5].c3, circles[5].c4);
 }
}

class Stem { 
int initalloX=200;
int initalloY=800;

Stem(int tempInitalloX, int tempInitalloY) {
  initalloX = tempInitalloX;
  initalloY = tempInitalloY;

}

void drawStem() {
  background(#0DBADB);
  scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
  stroke (12, 149, 11);
  fill (12, 149, 11);
  strokeWeight(10);
  line(initalloX, initalloY, initalloX, ((frameCount>250)?initalloY-500:initalloY-(2*frameCount)));
  //stem1
  if (frameCount>101) {
    noStroke();
    translate(initalloX, initalloY-200);
    scale(min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1), min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1));
    beginShape();
    vertex(0, 0);
    bezierVertex(-40, -5, -30, -40, -80, -20);
    bezierVertex(-47, -16, -52, 8, 0, 0);
    endShape(CLOSE);
    scale(1/min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1), 1/min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1));
    translate(-initalloX, -(initalloY-200));
    noStroke();
  }
  //stem2
  if (frameCount>151) {
//  noStroke();
    translate(initalloX, initalloY-300);
    scale(-min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1), min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1));
    beginShape();
    vertex(0, 0);
    bezierVertex(-40, -5, -30, -40, -80, -20);
    bezierVertex(-47, -16, -52, 8, 0, 0);
    endShape(CLOSE);
    scale(-1/min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1), 1/min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1));
    translate(-initalloX, -(initalloY-300));

    }
  }
 }

class Circle {

  int c1 = 0;
  int c2 = -40;
  float c3 = 50;
  float c4 = 50;

  Circle(int tc1, int tc2, float tc3, float tc4) {
    c1 = tc1;
    c2 = tc2;
    c3 = tc3;
    c4 = tc4;
   }
 }
```

This is a function in a program, and it is written in Processing.
Thanks in advance for help/input!

Comment: What are you painting back to??

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean?

Comment: Are you using Swing, AWT, SWT some other graphics toolkit

Comment: He is using Processing.org which, I think, uses AWT behind the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_hi theolc, for your growing flower i would do something like this, a very simple start for you ;). See if it help. I choosed to go by trigonometry as it appeared to me to be easier to control than rotation in this case. Check it out (click mouse to grow/ click holding any key to shrink):

```
Stem myStem;
Circle circles[];
Flower p = new Flower();

float scaleFactor=0.5;


void setup() {


  size(floor(400*scaleFactor), floor(800*scaleFactor));
  myStem = new Stem(200, 800);
  p = new Flower (0, 0);
  //mpoved this to setup, no need to recreate each frame
  circles = new Circle[6];
  circles[0]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
  circles[1]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
  circles[2]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
  circles[3]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
  circles[4]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
  circles[5]  = new Circle(0, 0, 50, 50);
  // also smooth only needs to be called once
  // unless ther is a noSmooth() somewhere
  smooth();
}

void draw() {

  float grow = 0;
  //translate(myStem.initalloX, myStem.initalloY);  
  myStem.drawStem();
  //set centre point
  if (frameCount>grow) {

    translate(myStem.initalloX, ((frameCount>250)?myStem.initalloY-      500:myStem.initalloY-(2*frameCount)));


    fill(170, 14, 24); // red
    for (int i = 0; i < circles.length-1; i++) {
      ellipse(circles[i].c1+grow, circles[i].c2+grow, circles[i].c3+grow, circles[i].c4+grow);
      rotate(radians(72));
    }
    fill(14, 17, 170); // blue
    ellipse(circles[5].c1, circles[5].c2, circles[5].c3, circles[5].c4);
    p.grow();
  }

  p.display();
}

class Stem { 
  int initalloX=200;
  int initalloY=800;

  Stem(int tempInitalloX, int tempInitalloY) {
    initalloX = tempInitalloX;
    initalloY = tempInitalloY;
  }

  void drawStem() {
    background(#0DBADB);
    scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    stroke (12, 149, 11);
    fill (12, 149, 11);
    strokeWeight(10);
    line(initalloX, initalloY, initalloX, ((frameCount>250)?initalloY-500:initalloY-(2*frameCount)));
    //stem1
    if (frameCount>101) {
      noStroke();
      translate(initalloX, initalloY-200);
      scale(min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1), min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1));
      beginShape();
      vertex(0, 0);
      bezierVertex(-40, -5, -30, -40, -80, -20);
      bezierVertex(-47, -16, -52, 8, 0, 0);
      endShape(CLOSE);
      scale(1/min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1), 1/min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1));
      translate(-initalloX, -(initalloY-200));
      noStroke();
    }
    //stem2
    if (frameCount>151) {
      //  noStroke();
      translate(initalloX, initalloY-300);
      scale(-min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1), min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1));
      beginShape();
      vertex(0, 0);
      bezierVertex(-40, -5, -30, -40, -80, -20);
      bezierVertex(-47, -16, -52, 8, 0, 0);
      endShape(CLOSE);
      scale(-1/min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1), 1/min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1));
      translate(-initalloX, -(initalloY-300));
    }
  }
}

class Circle {

  int c1 = 0;
  int c2 = -40;
  float c3 = 50;
  float c4 = 50;

  Circle(int tc1, int tc2, float tc3, float tc4) {
    c1 = tc1;
    c2 = tc2;
    c3 = tc3;
    c4 = tc4;
  }
}






class Flower {


  float centerX;
  float centerY;
  float posX;
  float posY;
  float maxSize = 51;
  float maxFactor = 40;
  float sizes = 0;
  float factor = 0;
  float speed = 0.17;

  Flower() {
  }
  Flower(float _centerX, float _centerY)
  {
    centerX = _centerX;
    centerY = _centerY;
  }

  void setCenter(float x, float y)
  {
    centerX = x;
    centerY = y;
  }

  void display()
  {
    for (int i = -18; i < 360; i+=72)
    {
       posX = centerX + cos(radians(i)) * factor;
       posY = centerY + sin(radians(i)) * factor;
      noStroke();
      fill(14, 170, 170 ); // blue
      ellipse(posX, posY, sizes, sizes);
    }
    fill(145, 170, 170);

    ellipse(centerX, centerY, sizes , sizes );
  }


  void grow()
  {
    factor = (factor < maxFactor )?  factor + speed: maxFactor;
    sizes = (sizes < maxSize )?  sizes + speed*1.3 : maxSize;

  }
}// end of Flower
```

Comment: i edited the code in the question... Maybe it could help answer my original question more??? Thanks again guys for helping me out!

Comment: v.k. you are amazing my friend! thank you very much for your help!